# How to create a radio button group with custom PickerStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swiftui

PickerStyle offers WheelPickerStyle, SegmentedPickerStyle and more. I want to customise it create a radio buttons that only one should be selected at a time.

I am Android Developer and very new to swift. I am using **SwiftUI** for my UI needs.

I looked into the documentation and there is a PickerStyle protocol but I am not able to implement it and didn't find any tutorial. I have following code for this:

```
struct RadioPickerStyle: PickerStyle {

    static func _makeView<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_PickerValue<RadioPickerStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewInputs) -> _ViewOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
//        Text("\(value)")
    }

    static func _makeViewList<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_PickerValue<RadioPickerStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewListInputs) -> _ViewListOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
//        List(inputs) {
//            ForEach
//        }
    }
```

I want to use it in the following code:

```
...
    @State var gender: Int = 0
    let genderOptions: [String] = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
...
                    Picker("Gender", selection: $gender) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< genderOptions.count) { option in
                            Text(self.genderOptions[option])
                                .tag(self.gender)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(RadioPickerStyle())
...
```

Does anyone can give me idea of what is `_ViewInputs`, `_ViewOutputs` ,`_ViewListInputs` and `_ViewListOutputs`?

Comment: Those are private types... making custom `PickerStyle` is not allowed for now.

Comment: Strange! o_O Why they allowed me to implement `PickerStyle` on `RadioPickerStyle` struct?

Comment: If you'd really implemented it, there would not be this question here. ;)

Comment: I mean, I am able to write `struct RadioPickerStyle: PickerStyle` and I didn't get any error here..

Comment: Anyway, I got it that the underscore classes are Private and I can't make mine PickerStyle :(

Answer (score 0):

using this code you get tag value in selected variable.

```
@State private var selected : Int = 0

Picker("Gender:", selection: $selected){
    Text("Male").tag(0)
    Text("Female").tag(1)
    Text("Male").tag(0)   
}.pickerStyle(RadioPickerStyle())

Text("\(selected)")
```

Comment: `RadioPickerStyle` doesn't seem available in iOS now.